# How to convert keyword to integer in Kibana 5 using painless script?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

[image]I want to order `Hour` values in Ascending order in a bar chart of Kibana 5:

The problem is that the order is `0, 1, 10, 2, ...` instead of `0, 1, 2, 3, ...`. The possible reason is that `Hour` is a keyword, not integer. In Elasticsearch I can see `"Hour": "1"`, etc.

Is it possible to convert `Hour` values to integer on the fly in Kibana?

Comment: Converting data types on fly is not possible and that is not recommended too. You should fix your base( ES index) for it.

Comment: I found out that it's possible to create a scripted field like Integer.parseInt(doc["Hour"].value)

Comment: Yeah. Scripted fields of Kibana can be a choice but it would impact performance. Use it carefully.